# Is safe using $sample and updateOne on mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was looking for a solution to findOneAndUpdate a random document and I've found this:

[Find One and Update with random document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096708/find-one-and-update-with-random-document)

I had already thinked in that solution from accepted answer but I thought this could result in a race condition. Is that possible? I thought if two people call the same function at the same time, there is a chance of both get the same random document and one update will be overwritten with the other one. If race condition is possible in this case what can I do to find a random document and update in proper way? I have to set a pessimistic lock?

Comment: Yes, there's a race condition. Whether that's an actual issue depends on what exactly you want to do with the document. As long as you're using [update operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/) you can rely on the fact that document updates are performed atomically.